# How to display only the multiple maximal values of my result table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this MySQL queries on my database:

```
SELECT movie.name, SUM(heroes.likes) AS 'success'
FROM heroebymovie JOIN 
     heroes
     ON heroes.ID = heroebymovie.heroID JOIN
     movie
     ON movie.ID = heroebymovie.movieID
GROUP BY movie.ID
ORDER BY SUM(heroes.likes) DESC
```

I obtain this result:

```
|name                       |success  |
|Avengers 2                 |72317559 |
|Avengers                   |72317559 |
|Captain America : Civil War|67066832 |
```

I would like to display only the movies with the highest number of “success” (in this case “Avengers 2” and “Avengers”).
Can someone explain the way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is using an having clause that filter for the max value  ( in this case the ordered list of sum desc limit 1)

```
SELECT movie.name, SUM(heroes.likes) AS success
FROM heroebymovie JOIN heroes ON heroes.ID = heroebymovie.heroID 
JOIN movie ON movie.ID = heroebymovie.movieID
GROUP BY movie.ID 
HAVING success = (
    SELECT SUM(heroes.likes) 
    FROM heroebymovie JOIN heroes ON heroes.ID = heroebymovie.heroID 
    JOIN movie ON movie.ID = heroebymovie.movieID
    GROUP BY movie.ID
    ORDER BY SUM(heroes.likes) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY SUM(heroes.likes) DESC
```

Comment: This method looks good, but I have a syntax error near: `HAVING success = (
    SELECT SUM(heroes.likes) 
    FROM heroebymovie JOIN he` on line 6

Comment: @MarieDeschamps   wrong order  by position .. answer updated

Comment: there is an extra right parenthesis in this request

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a limit, but want to consider ties. MySQL supports the `LIMIT` clause, but unfortunately no accompanying ties expression.

In standard SQL you would simply add

```
FETCH 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

and be done with it. (SQL Server does the same with `TOP(1) WITH TIES`.)

Another way would be to use standard SQL's `MAX OVER`: `MAX(SUM(heroes.likes)) OVER()` and only keep rows where the sum matches the maximum. Or use `RANK OVER`. But again, MySQL doesn't support either of these.

So your main option is to execute the query twice, like in this pseudo code:

```
select sum ... having sum = (select max(sum) ...)
```

An easy way to get the max of the sums in MySQL is to order by sums descending and limit the results to one row.

```
SELECT m.name, SUM(h.likes) AS "success"
FROM heroebymovie hm
JOIN heroes h ON h.ID = hm.heroID
JOIN movie m ON m.ID = hm.movieID
GROUP BY m.ID
HAVING SUM(h.likes) =
(
  SELECT SUM(h2.likes)
  FROM heroebymovie hm2
  JOIN heroes h2 ON h2.ID = hm2.heroID
  GROUP BY hm2.movieID
  ORDER BY SUM(h2.likes) DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```